# bjam acting weird?

Tags: boost, bjam

I thought the output of this code would be

```
Hello World 1
Hello World 2 3
```

But I get

```
Hello World 1
Hello World 2 Hello World 3
```

Here's the jam code

```
rule weird ( a : b + : c * : d ? )
{
  echo "Hello World $(a)" ;
  echo "Hello World $(b)" ;
}

weird 1 : 2 3 ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jam's variable expansion rules are very different from other languages.  From the [boost jam documentation](http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/jam/language.html):

> The result of a token after variable expansion is the product of the components of the token, where each component is a literal substring or a list substituting a variable reference.

So jam is expanding "Hello World $(b)" to "Hello World $(b[1])" "Hello World$(b[2])" and echoing that.

If you want "Hello World 2 3", you need to split the echo argument into two tokens

```
echo "Hello World" $(b) ;
```